# How to back to a root HTML tag with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to use the **`td.ms-vb-title`** in order to get the text `2,004`, `2,005`, `2,006` in the class `ms-vb2` attribute.

I tried to use `prev()` but it didn't work...

**HTML:**

```
<tbody>
        <tr iid="92,1,0" class="ms-itmhover" setedgeborder="true">
            <td class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell">
                <input type="checkbox" class="s4-itm-cbx"></td>
            <td class="ms-vb2"></td>
            <td height="100%" class="ms-vb-title" onmouseover="OnChildItem(this)" id="msomenuid2"></td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">
                <div align="right">2,004</div>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">
                <div align="right">1,000</div>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">
                <div align="right">400</div>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell">
                <div align="right">600</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr iid="92,2,0" class="ms-alternating ms-itmhover" setedgeborder="true">
            <td class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell">
                <input type="checkbox" class="s4-itm-cbx"></td>
            <td class="ms-vb2"></td>
            <td height="100%" class="ms-vb-title" onmouseover="OnChildItem(this)"></td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">
                <div align="right">2,005</div>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">
                <div align="right">1,170</div>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">
                <div align="right">460</div>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell">
                <div align="right">1,200</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr iid="92,3,0" class="ms-itmhover" setedgeborder="true">
            <td class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell">
                <input type="checkbox" class="s4-itm-cbx"></td>
            <td class="ms-vb2"></td>
            <td height="100%" class="ms-vb-title" onmouseover="OnChildItem(this)"></td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">
                <div align="right">2,006</div>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">
                <div align="right">660</div>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">
                <div align="right">1,120</div>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell">
                <div align="right">780</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var arrayList = $("td.ms-vb-title:contains('')");
            var a = $(arrayList).prev().eq(0).find("ms-vb2");
            alert(arrayList.length);
            alert(a.length);
            $.each(arrayList, function (i, e) {
                areaname[i] = $(e).text();
            });
```

Comment: exactly What OP you want when mouse over event of "ms-vb-title" class?

Comment: I wanna get the text `2,004`, `2,005`, `2,006` in `ms-vb2` attribute with the usage of `td.ms-vb-title`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree

Change your code to

```
 var a = $(arrayList).closest('tr').find(".ms-vb2");
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. If I would like to get the first class named `ms-vb2`, I will use `var a = $(arrayList).closest()('tr').find(".ms-vb2").eq(0);` Is that correct?

Comment: @PMay1903: this would be correct `$(arrayList).closest('tr').find(".ms-vb2").eq(0);`

Comment: That works pretty well actually as your second edited code. Thank you very much!

Comment: with your code `var a = $(arrayList).closest('tr').find(".ms-vb2");` and if I have **`<tbody><tr>1</tr><tr>2</tr><tr>3</tr></tbody>`** and I wanna back to the **`<tbody>`** tag, how can I reduce the code into **one line** instead of added more `var b = ...`?

Comment: @PMay1903, I was away from my desk, that a typo while answering, Context is not clear for `I wanna back to the <tbody> tag`, traverse from where?

Comment: It's OK. I'll wait for you to come back home. Besides that, I have edited the thread to make it easy to get what I mean, please have a look on it.